# Error 'Ending position out of bounds: 7' in LightningSelfRegisterControllerTest.testSelfRegistration

Tags: apex

Seeing the following when we run the `LightningSelfRegisterControllerTest`:

```
LightningSelfRegisterControllerTest  testSelfRegistration  System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Passwords did not match., Actual: Ending position out of bounds: 7  Class.LightningSelfRegisterControllerTest.testSelfRegistration: line 26, column 1
```

From what I can see, this may be down to a bug in `LightningSelfRegisterController`:

```
...
            nickname += String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger()).substring(1,7);
...
```

I guess if `getRandomInteger` generates a number less than 1,000,000, then this would lead to the error above. Has anyone else seen this or know where I can raise a bug report for this? (I'm completely new to salesforce, so not sure where this code comes from :( ).

Answer (score 3):

Use the String#left method to extract up to the first seven characters:

```
nickname += String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger()).left(7);
```

Unlike String#substring, this method won't throw an error when there's less than the requested number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of random Integer before before extracting substring.

```
Integer num = Crypto.getRandomInteger();
String stringNum = String.valueOf(num);
if(stringNum.length() > 7 ) {
    nickname +=stringNum.substring(1,7);
}
```